# How to grep a date lesser than a particular date in a file

Tags: grep, date

I have a log file like Blah blah blah 2018-12-13.  Now I want to grep the log files with a date before 2018-05-01.  My intention is to filter the Log files lesser than 2018-05-01

Comment: does the date always occur at end of line? try `awk '$NF < "2018-05-01"'`

Comment: Add an example chunk, and your desired output from that.

Comment: Is the spring "Blah blah blah 2018-12-13" a line in a log file or a name of a file?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `awk`'s [comparison operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html)

```
$ cat ip.txt 
Blah blah blah 2018-12-13
Blah blah blah 2018-02-13
Blah blah blah 2018-05-01

$ awk '$NF < "2018-05-01"' ip.txt 
Blah blah blah 2018-02-13
```

To get lines less than or equal to some date:

```
$ awk '$NF <= "2018-05-01"' ip.txt 
Blah blah blah 2018-02-13
Blah blah blah 2018-05-01
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Just another tip. If your date field is in the first column `2018-12-13 Blah blah blah`
`2018-02-13 Blah blah blah`
`2018-05-01 Blah blah blah` just replace `$NF` with `$1`. Or with `$3` if it is in the 3rd column, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dategrep` from dateutils, http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/

```
dategrep '<2018-05-01' <file
```